# How to make sense of disk volumes and partitions?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, mount

I've recently dual booted my laptop and I'm not sure if the partitions were organized properly.

I had a 240GB Disk that I partitioned into 2 volumes, one for Windows and one for Ubuntu.

After dual booting, I checked my disk volumes and I'm seeing `/dev/sda1` through `/dev/sda5` now :

```
Partition 1 - 105MB FAT, mounted at /boot/efi, partition type : EFI system
Partition 2 - 17MB Unknown, unknown contents, partition type : Microsoft reserved
Partition 3 - 115GB NTFS, not mounted, partition type : Basic Data
Partition 4 - 633MB NTFS, not mounted, partition type : Microsoft Windows Recovery Environment (System)
Partition 5 - 125GB Ext4, mounted at Filesystem Root, partition type : Linux Filesystem
```

I'm suspecting that both Windows and Linux are using Partition 5 simultaneously because they appear to have the same disk space available - although this is not what I aimed for.

How do I troubleshoot and make sense out of all of this?

Answer (score 1):

Your system looks normal for a dual-boot setup.

Partition 1: [EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition)

Partitions 2,3,4: Windows

- The clues here are references to the NTFS filesystem and to Microsoft. Explaining the various Windows partitions is best done in a Windows support venue.

Partition 5: Ubuntu

- The clue here is the reference to the ext4 filesystem. FYI: Windows cannot read an ext4 partition without add-ons, so it is unlikely that Windows is using Partition 5.